# Django OneToOneField subset of a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, subset, one-to-one

Basically I am writing a website to models Sports Teams and I have two models, Player and Team. A Team has a ManyToManyField relationship with player and also a OneToOneField representing the captain which should be limited to the players on the team (i.e. you can't have a captain that isn't one of the players).

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    .....

class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    captain = models.OneToOneField(Player)
    ....
```

Basically what I am wanting to know what is the best way to limit the OneToOneField, captain, to only select one of those players on the team.

I have tried

```
limit_choices_to={'team_set__players__name__icontains':""}
```

as a kwarg and the only other way I think could work would be a custom validator on the captain field that does a database lookup, but surely there must be a better way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you creating teams and players in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `clean` method on your `Team` model. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Team(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        if self.captain not in self.players.all():
             raise ValidationError("Captain must be already be a player")
```

Your `clean` will method be called when automatically when `is_valid` is run on the model.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using this method a lot with forms but never thought to do it on the models.